# Centralizing getting of a session variable in a Jersey REST resource

Tags: java, jersey

## Problem Definition

I'm converting a legacy app to use a REST api where each method requires getting data from a session variable (I know it's not truly a REST application, but it's legacy code).

I'd like to keep the code DRY, so I tried setting the session variable in the constructor, but the `HttpServletRequest` isn't ready during construction. I'd like to set the `User` variable in one place. What is the proper way to do this?

### Code Sample

```
@Path("/someResource")
public class SomeResource {
  @Context
  HttpServletRequest currentRequest;

  private User user = null;

  public SomeResource() {
    // This doesn't work
    // HttpSession session = currentRequest.getSession();
    // user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
  }

  @GET
  @Produces ( ... )
  @PermitAll
  @Path( ... )
  public findById read(...) {
    HttpSession session = currentRequest.getSession();
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    ...
  }

  @GET
  @Produces ( ... )
  @PermitAll
  @Path( ... )
  public findByName read(...) {
    HttpSession session = currentRequest.getSession();
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    ...
  }

  @GET
  @Produces ( ... )
  @PermitAll
  @Path( ... )
  public someResource findAll (...) {
    HttpSession session = currentRequest.getSession();
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    ...
  }

  ... many other paths, etc... each checking the user session variable.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Security information of a request is available by injecting a JAX-RS SecurityContext instance using @Context annotation. The injected security context instance provides the **equivalent of the functionality available on HttpServletRequest** API"

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html#d0e10543

Hope that helps